# Azure function dotnet isolated process (DotnetWorker) Got strange exception

Tags: azure-functions, azure-http-trigger, dotnet-isolated

I got the below exception when implementing the POST method

```
[2022-06-17T07:14:41.723Z] Executed 'Functions.AuthenticateHttpTrigger' (Failed, Id=12bb7c91-4030-4090-a2fe-ec205702c662, Duration=424954ms)
[2022-06-17T07:14:41.726Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.AuthenticateHttpTrigger. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Duplicate binding call detected. Input parameters can only be bound to arguments once. Use the InputArguments property to inspect values.
[2022-06-17T07:14:41.727Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Context.Features.DefaultModelBindingFeature.BindFunctionInput(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Context\Features\DefaultModelBindingFeature.cs:line 29
[2022-06-17T07:14:41.728Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionExecutor.cs:line 37
[2022-06-17T07:14:41.729Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.OutputBindings.OutputBindingsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\OutputBindings\OutputBindingsMiddleware.cs:line 13
```

Have you encountered an issue like that? please advise.

Thanks in advance.

============================================

EDIT

Here is my function definition

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
[Function(nameof(AuthenticateHttpTrigger))]
[OpenApiOperation(operationId: nameof(AuthenticateHttpTrigger), Description = "Authenticate")]
[OpenApiRequestBody(contentType: Constants.CommonResponseContentType, bodyType: typeof(AuthenticationRequest))]
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: Constants.CommonResponseContentType, bodyType: typeof(AuthenticationResponse), Description = "The OK response")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "authenticate")] HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    try
    {
        _logTrace.Add(LogLevel.Info, $"{nameof(AuthenticateHttpTrigger)} - AUTHENTICATE START", new { });
        var requestUser = executionContext.Features.Get<JwtPrincipalFeature>()?.User;
        var requestData = await req.GetBodyAsync<AuthenticationRequest>();
        var addUserCommand = new AuthenticateCommand
        {
            RequestUser = requestUser,
            Data = requestData,
            LogTrace = _logTrace
        };

        return await _httpFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
        {
            var result = await _mediator.Send(addUserCommand);

            _logTrace.Add(LogLevel.Info, $"{nameof(AuthenticateHttpTrigger)} - AUTHENTICATE END ", new { result });

            return result.Success
                ? CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, req, result.Data)
                : CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity, req, null);
        }, req);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logTrace.AddError(e);
        return CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity, req, null);
    }
    finally
    {
        _logTrace.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your function definition.

Comment: @TanveerBadar I have just edited the question and put a detailed function definition. Thanks.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by breaking the middleware.
Something like this
```if (targetMethod?.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), false) is AllowAnonymousAttribute)
            {
                await next(context);
                return;
            }```

Answer (score 1):

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.AuthenticateHttpTrigger. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Duplicate binding call detected. Input parameters can only be bound to arguments once. Use the InputArguments property to inspect values.

The Error message shows that in your function execution the **input Arguments are duplicated**. You have to avoid the duplication of ***InputArgument*** it should be bound once while executing the function.

I hope you fixed the same way by using [GetCustomAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attribute.getcustomattribute?view=net-6.0).

```cs
if(targetMethod?.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), false) is AllowAnonymousAttribute) 
{ 
    await next(context); return; 
}
```

Refer the [blog](https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-jwt-authentication-in-net-isolated-process-azure-functions) for more information

Comment: Yes, I use middleware for authorization and authentication. If I bypass the validation, I put the `return` statement to fix the issue. Thansk